# Parse query not contained in relation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform

I am a bit new to swift and parse, and could use some help. I am running a query of all users on my database, so that you can tap on one and add them to your friendRelation. But when they reload they should not see users that are already in the relation. Here is what I have so far:

```
private func fetchUsers() {

    let userQuery = PFUser.query()
    userQuery?.whereKey("email", containedIn: PFUser.currentUser()!["contacts"] as! [AnyObject])

    //I need a constraint to say whereKey email/objId not in friendRelation

    userQuery?.orderByAscending("username")
    userQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (users, error) in

        if error == nil {

            self.users = users as! [PFUser]
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }) 
}
```

Does anyone know how to make that constraint?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display all user which are **not** your friends you should use **notContainedIn** in your where clause because you want to get all the users which are not your friends.

In your code you check for the email field. it will work only if your contacts array will be an array which contain only emails. I think it's better to go with one of the following approaches:

1. Your contact array should contain an array of the user **objectId** and not email and then your where should look like this:

```js
userQuery ? .whereKey("objectId", notContainedIn: PFUser.currentUser() !["contacts"] as![AnyObject])
```

it's always better to use ids and not other fields for better performance (there are more reasons)

2. Your contacts array should contain a list of your user objects and then you should use different type of query and use whereKey:doesNotMatchKey:inQuery: option